# Does AWS DBInstance maintenance keep data intact

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are using CloudFormation Template to create MySQL AWS::RDS::DBInstance.

My question is when there is maintenance in progress while applying OS upgrades or software/security patches, will

- Database Instance be unavailable for the time of maintenance
- Does it wipe out data from database instance during maintenance?
- If answer to first is yes, will using DBCluster help avoid that short downtime, if I use more than one instances?

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Maintenance.html) I did not receive any indication that there is any loss of data possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Database Instance be unavailable for the time of maintenance

They may reboot the server to apply the maintenance. I've personally never seen anything more than a reboot, but I suppose it's possible they may have to shut it down for a few minutes.

> Does it wipe out data from database instance during maintenance?

Definitely not.

> If answer to first is yes, will using DBCluster help avoid that short
>   downtime, if I use more than one instances?

Yes, a database in cluster mode would fail-over to another node while they were applying patches to one node.

Answer (score 0):

I am actively working of RDS Database system from the last 5 years. Based on my experience, my answer to your questions as follows in BOLD.

Database Instance be unavailable for the time of maintenance
[**Yes, Your RDS system will be unavailable during maintenance of database**] 
Does it wipe out data from database instance during maintenance?
[ **Definitely BIG NO** ] 
If answer to first is yes, will using DBCluster help avoid that short downtime, if I use more than one instances?
[**Yes, In cluster Mode or Multi A-Z Deployment, Essentially AWS apply the patches on the backup node or replica first and then failover to this patch instance. Last, there would be some downtime during the g switchover process**]